# How to unzip a zipfile attachment in apex and process each file in the zip attachment

Tags: apex-email-service, zip

I am trying to unzip a zip file attachment. but, unable to unzip the attachment and process all the internal files in the zip file.
I want to do this using an email handler class.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this natively in Apex using the Zippex library which is open source.
https://github.com/pdalcol/Zippex

Your code would be similar to this:

```
Blob zipBlob; //This needs to contain the zip file

Zippex myZip = new Zippex(zipBlob);

//Loop through the files in Zip and process them
for (String fileName : myZip.getFileNames()) {

    Blob fileData = myZip.getFile(fileName);

    //Process fileData here.

}
```

Comment: Pedro, Thank you for sharing this. This is exactly what I was looking for....Very cool!

Comment: This is very cool library. I try to use it in Apex to extract 86.7 KB JSON out of 11 KB Zip file and code failed with LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded, FATAL_ERROR Class.Puff.codes: line 416, column 1

Comment: Maximum CPU time: 15020 out of 10000. Is there any way to get it work under Apex CPU Time limit?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no native zip support in APEX right now. But you can help yourself using a very good Javascript zip tool like http://stuk.github.io/jszip/

On how to use it, look at
http://andyinthecloud.com/2012/11/04/handling-office-files-and-zip-files-in-apex-part-1/

and
http://andyinthecloud.com/category/zip/

Comment: Close, but it won't work for apex code. However, I'm working on a batch class version since the new ten minute limit was introduced.

Comment: @sfdcfox sounds very interesting. Will you share your approach? Can you elaborate on how you do it or post a link?