# How can decompress gzip file in salesforce

Tags: apex, javascript, rest-api

I am doing SF integration With [Power Bill](https://www.getpowerbill.com/Service/Default.aspx). In the response i am getting a **gzip file** with `encoding-format: application/x-gzip`. I want to decompress this file into Sf but not able to find any solution. I also tried various Javascript solution like [pako](https://github.com/nodeca/pako), [jszip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) and many other also.

I also tried to save this file in attachment as zip and then try to parse still don't get any success. Does anybody know here how can i decompress this file in Apex or in Javascript. Please let me know thanks.

Comment: Was there an issue with the solution referenced [here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/43941/how-to-unzip-a-zipfile-attachment-in-apex-and-process-each-file-in-the-zip-attac)

Comment: @DeveloperWonk thanks for the link but it supports only zip file but i am getting gzip file in response.

Comment: [CloudConvert](https://cloudconvert.com/) has an API.  You may be able to send the gzip response through their API and convert to Zip.

Comment: @DeveloperWonk yes but it will not work in my case. It will give download url and i want the file in the response.